# How to send email on Adobe Air + backbone.js application

Tags: javascript, air, pug

I have developed a web application using Adobe Air and Backbone.js. I'm using jade template to create a contact form. The jade code of the form look like below:

```
div.span6.span_col_2.custom_span6#rightContact
            div.well.well-large.well-custom
                form.form-horizontal
                    fieldset
                        input(type="hidden" name="type_contact" value="")
                        - inco = { fkey:"contact_description" }
                        include field_textarea_val
                        - inco = { fkey:"contact_email" }
                        include field_text_val
                        - inco = { fkey:"contact_phone" }
                        include field_text_val
                        a#sendBtn.btn.btn-warning( imsg="send", href="#rwSendContact" )
```

When user click send button, all content from input fields will send to the controller. Please look at the controller code as below:

```
var ContactRouter =
Backbone.Router.extend(
    {
        routes:
            {
                "rwSendContact": "sendcontact"
            },
        sendcontact: function(){
            var values = getFieldValuesInContact();
            var service_id = 'myservice';
            var template_id = 'welcome';
            var template_params = {
                  name: 'John',
                  reply_email: 'myemail@yahoo.com',
                  message: 'This is awesome!'
            };
            emailjs.send(service_id,template_id,template_params);
        }
    });

var contact = new ContactRouter();
```

From the line `emailjs.send(service_id,template_id,template_params);`, I want a library that can help me to send email. Can you guys give me a suggestion for what library can I use to archive this?

Regards,

Comment: take a look at https://www.mandrill.com/

Comment: It's not free! By the way, it still need a server to send email while my project is a desktop application.